# Fetch Bootstrap Dropdown Value OnSubmit

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

**Dropdown made using `Bootstrap`**

```
<form id="search" action="" method="post" >
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Fixed <span class="caret"></span></button>

      <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Florida</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Texas</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Washington</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">New York</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Ohio</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery to keep dropdown option selected**

```
var jQee = jQuery.noConflict();
jQee(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
    var selText = jQee(this).text();
    jQee(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
    //jQee('#search').submit();
});
```

**HTML Dropdown**

```
<select onchange="form.submit()" name="template">
    <option value="F" selected="true">Florida</option>
    <option value="T">Texas</option>
    <option value="W">Washington</option>
    <option value="N">New York</option>
    <option value="O">Ohio</option>
</select>
```

For the above dropdown, I am fetching the `option value` based on user selection.

While doing it with `Bootstrap`, I am able to keep the the dropdown value `selected`, but as I am using it with `PHP`, I also need the value in `$_POST` variable in order to execute `SQL` query and display results based on what value is selected from dropdown.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden field and populate it when the user selects a state.

HTML

```
<form id="search" action="" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="selection">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Fixed <span class="caret"></span></button>

      <ul aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Florida</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Texas</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Washington</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">New York</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Ohio</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li a").click(function() {
        text = $(this).closest("li").text();
        $("input[name='selection']").val(text);
        $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(text+' <span class="caret"></span>');
        $("#search").submit();
    });
});
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44psav3j/18/) Use inspect element to check the value of the hidden field.

Comment: The value is changed for hidden input and I am submitting form to fetch POST value. But then it does not keep the option value selected in dropdown.

Comment: I have combined it with your code. If you have the post value you can let PHP set the value for the hidden input field and button text on the server side if applicable.

Comment: `$(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(text+' <span class="caret"></span>');` and `$('#search').submit();` are not working together. I can make values selected but can't get it in `POST`

Comment: Added the post code. You will get a forbidden error in JSFiddle but the value is posted with name 'selection'.

Comment: Do you mean `$("#search").submit()` to post value ?

Comment: Yes, this will post the form including the hidden field value.

Comment: But then it does not keep the value selected in dropdown

Comment: That's odd. Is the page fully refreshed after the post action?

Comment: Yes. The value is selected and then the form is submitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62248/discussion-between-barry-and-slimshadddyyy).

Comment: what if the dropdown has option 'Please Select' ?

Comment: $caption = (isset($_POST['selection'])) ? $_POST['selection'] : 'Please Select';

Comment: The above code provides `Please Select` option but after selecting any value from dropdown, the `Please Select` option does not appear again.

Comment: So, please select is shown. The user selects a state and the state is shown. When must the text please select be shown again?

Comment: `Please select` is shown only once. When any option is changed from dropdown, it does not appear.