# How to insert Bootstrap drop-down values in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap for making a user form.
Now i need to insert selected drop-down value in database.
But i am facing two problems.

1) When i select any item from drop-down, it jumps to top of my screen in url because of href="#". When i removed "#", it started the page refresh on selection item.

2) How i target my drop-down list to insert any selected value in database using php.

My code is

```
 <div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select City
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Lahore</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Islamabad</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">karachi</a></li>
</ul>
   </div>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: @Banik
See mu updated question

Comment: first of all write href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: @Banik
works!
Next ?

Comment: remove $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
write $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').attr('data-value',$(this).text());

Comment: @Banik
great job !
Now where i should give like name="city" to insert values in database ?
In <ul> or somewhere else ?

Comment: wherever you want but you have to fetch it according to the tree...

Comment: @Banik
Tht's the point, i am asking that how will i get it as tree.
I am new on Bootstrap.

Comment: I think you dont have to add any attribute now.Just alert($('.dropdown-toggle').data('value'));

Comment: @Banik
how would i insert in db?
What will be the syntax for php ?

Comment: you can do two things either
1. Write the query in a file, then use in html $.ajax where url key will be the php file and data key will be the $('.dropdown-toggle').data('value')
or 
2. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138224/fetch-bootstrap-dropdown-value-onsubmit?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Banik
you are talking about to take this action
 dataType: $('.dropdown-toggle').data('value');
Right?

Comment: @Banik
did not work !

Comment: not dataType its data

Comment: @Banik
Check is this ok?
 $.post("complainForm_php.php",{name: $(this).text()}, {data: $('.dropdown-toggle').data('value')},
         function(response){
        alert("Response from server: "+response);
        });
});

Comment: no syntax is not right.You can use $.post but I always prefer... $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {name : $('.dropdown-toggle').data('value')},
  success: function(data){
     alert("Response from server: "+response);
 },
  error: function(errorThrown){
      alert(errorThrown);
 }
});

Comment: @Banik
What is data in function(data)?

Comment: data is the 'response' from the php side after successfull insertion.

Comment: @Banik
After including your suggested code in my js file, i tried to save values in database like this
    $complain_dropdown =$_POST['name']; 
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO information (user_id,complain_dropdown) 
VALUES ('$id' , '$complain_dropdown')";
 $res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
It reeturns null value with error Undefine index "name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the point 1** :
Since you have the `#` in the href the page scrolls up (i.e. navigating to the link target). You can prevent this event by adding `event.preventDefault()` in your code.

**For Point 2**: Since you said if you are able to get the value to your server side php code then you can proceed further you can make use of **AJAX Post method**. The final code would be

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); //this is the line which prevents the event
      $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
      $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));

     //this is the code to post the value to server
     $.post("YourPHPMethod.php",{name: $(this).text()} ,function(response){
        alert("Response from server: "+response);
     });
});
```

Comment: And what about the PHP code for insert data into DB?

Comment: I am not a PHP guy, I am afraid I cant be helpful to you on that part.

Comment: @Reddy
oh it's ok.
I will appreciate for your effort and time .
God bless you.

Comment: Thanks, and should'nt it be a straight forward task to save to DB?? if you are experienced in PHP

Comment: @Reddy
Dear, actually it's a very straight forward task, if you are not using any framework.
My drop-down code is bootstrap specific so i am little confused that how may i target this drop-down in php as i am new on bootstrap :)

Comment: So when ever a dropdown is clicked you can pass that value to your php code right? If you get the value in your server side then you are ok to proceed?

Comment: @Reddy
Obviously dear :)

Comment: @Reddy
Where it comes from : "YourPHPMethod.php"?

Comment: There you have to give your php method url to which the value must be sent to.. And then you can save to DB from there

Comment: @Reddy
Message appears on selecting drop-down item but query is not inserting in db :(

Comment: Bro, the Ajax post which I have suggested will just send the value from the browser to your php code. its you who must write extra code in php to save the value into DB. I would suggest you to take a look on some blogs on how to save values into DB using php code.

Comment: @Reddy
I know how to retrieve value in client side code file. tell me one thing only.
     $.post("complainForm_php.php",{name: $(this).text()} 

what value, this ajax post sending to my client side code?
the value encode in name: ?
Means i should grab the name in my complainForm_php file?

Comment: the value its sending to your code is the anchor tag text on which you click. And yes you must have a input parameter for your method where the parameterName is `name`. You can grab the value from this input parameter.

Comment: @Reddy
no dude, i grabbed the value in server file but it returns empty value in db

Comment: hmmm not sure bro, it must be something with server code

Answer (score 0):

You have to post it to a php. I do it with ajax like this.

Look: http://www.codesheet.org/codesheet/wOHDXFju

```
function postContent(cv) {

  $("#myDiv").html('L  O  A  D  I  N  G ...').show();

  var url = "/post.php";

  $.post(url, {id: cv} ,function(data) {  //contentVar is the variable in post.php

       $("#myDiv").html(data).show();

    });
}
```

Comment: hey !
You code is not doing anything in your given link

Comment: sorry now it is doing